# JLabel unusable from other class

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, image-resizing

I got a problem with two problematics classes. One for drawing things, and other for implementing pan and zoom onto the previously drawn objects.

Imagine my interface as only two spitted panels, one empty(top) and one with a slider(bot):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

public class Interface {
private JFrame mainFrame;
public static void main(String[] args) {
  EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    try {Interface window = new Interface();window.mainFrame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}
   }
  });
}
public Interface() {initialize();}
private void initialize() {
  mainFrame = new JFrame();
  mainFrame.setTitle("LXView");
  mainFrame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
  mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  mainFrame.setExtendedState(mainFrame.getExtendedState()| JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
  mainFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
  mainFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
  JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane();
  splitPane.setOrientation(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
  splitPane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
  splitPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
  mainFrame.getContentPane().add(splitPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  splitPane.setResizeWeight(0.99);
  JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
  scrollPane.setEnabled(false);
  splitPane.setLeftComponent(scrollPane);
  Render topPane = new Render();
  scrollPane.setViewportView(topPane);
  topPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(topPane, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
  JPanel botPane = new JPanel();
  splitPane.setRightComponent(botPane);
  botPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));
  JLabel zoomLevel = new JLabel("Zoom level:");
  botPane.add(zoomLevel);
  JSlider slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 25, 100, 100);
  slider.setMajorTickSpacing(15);
  slider.setMinorTickSpacing(5);
  slider.setPaintTicks(true);
  slider.setPaintLabels(true);
  slider.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,40));
  botPane.add(slider);
  PanAndZoom zoomer=new PanAndZoom(topPane.getLabel());
  slider.addChangeListener(zoomer);
}
```

The top panel uses the render class which was made to draw graphics. Simplifying:

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class Render extends JPanel {
JLabel envContainer;
Render() {
  super();
  ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("/path/to/img1");
  JLabel envContainer = new JLabel(imageIcon);
  super.add(envContainer);
}
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
  super.paint(g);
  /*Render stuff*/
}
public JLabel getLabel() {
  return envContainer;
}
}
```

And the third class which is giving me the trouble, listens on the slider and sets the JLabel icon according to it:

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
public class PanAndZoom implements ChangeListener {
private JLabel label;
private BufferedImage image;


public PanAndZoom(JLabel lab){
  this.label=lab;
  try {
   image = ImageIO.read(new File("/path/to/img1"));
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("/path/to/img2"));//To test another img. It gives runtime errors.
}
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
  int value = ((JSlider) e.getSource()).getValue();
  double scale = value / 100.0;
  BufferedImage scaled = getScaledImage(scale); // It also gives runtime errors.
  System.out.println("Scale:"+scale+" Value:"+value);
  label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(scaled));
  label.revalidate();

}
private BufferedImage getScaledImage(double scale) {
  int w = (int) (scale * image.getWidth());
  int h = (int) (scale * image.getHeight());
  BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(w, h, image.getType());
  Graphics2D g2 = bi.createGraphics();
  g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
  AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(scale, scale);
  g2.drawRenderedImage(image, at);
  g2.dispose();
  return bi;
}
}
```

Why cant i use the JLabel if it was successfully returned by the getLabel method?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you "can't use" it? Are you receiving an error?

Comment: what is the runtime exception?? stack trace?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/TPSMax08
Interface is the first class, and PanAndZoom the latest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're local version of envContainer in class Render's constructor is overriding the class instance envContainer.

```
public class Render extends JPanel {
JLabel envContainer; //<---- class instance
Render() {
  super();
  ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("/path/to/img1");
  JLabel envContainer = new JLabel(imageIcon); //<---- overriden by local instance, hence class instance remains null
  super.add(envContainer);
}
```

My guess is that you didn't mean to make it a local version since you're not using it within the constructor for anything. Make the following change to your Render constructor.

```
Render() {
  ..
  this.envContainer = new JLabel(imageIcon);
  ...
}
```